# Mac - Python - import error: "No module named site"

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-requests, importerror

Tonight I am trying to get the package called "requests" installed and have begun fumbling around with the terminal and do not have very much intuition when it comes to this sort of thing.

Computer is a mac mini, osx version 10.9.4

In /Library/Python I have 4 folders: 2.3 2.5 2.6 and 2.7.
In /Applications I have "Python 2.7" and "Python 3.4"
I can open IDLE and type 8+8 and I get 16 just fine.

Here is the error I am getting in terminal:

```
 host-210-117:~ Mario$ python       
 ImportError: No module named site       

 host-210-117:~ Mario$ pip       
 ImportError: No module named site
```

My goal is to run this command in the terminal:

```
 pip install requests
```

I believe pip is already installed.  I run the file "get-pip.py" in IDLE and this is what it says:

> > > ```
> > >  Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg
> > >  Cleaning up...
> > > ```

This may have something to do with paths?  I would appreciate some guidance/hints/tips, thanks!

Oh and just a little more info that might help solve this question.  Here is the first few lines of the program I'm running:

```
 import base64
 import hmac
 import json
 import requests
 import time
 import urllib
 import os
```

Which gives me this error in IDLE (so I guess it importing those first few packages with no problem?) :

```
 >>> 

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/Mario/Desktop/pyak/pyak.py", line 4, in <module>
     import requests
 ImportError: No module named requests
 >>>
```

*****  System path list:

> > > sys.path
> > >       ['/Users/Mario/Desktop/pyak', '/Users/Mario/Documents', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

*** another update:

```
 host-210-117:~ Mario$ which python      
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

*** a little more info (is this supposed to happen?)

```
 host-210-117:~ Mario$ which pip       
 /usr/local/bin/pip        
 host-210-117:~ Mario$ pip       
 ImportError: No module named site
```

*** After changing .bashrc

.bashrc: here's what in the file

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
alias python=/Library/Python/2.7/python

here is the output of running:

```
  pip install requests
```

host-210-117:~ Mario$ pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (458kB): 458kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: requests
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Mario/Library/Logs/pip.log

Comment: A bit simpler option - open a terminal and type `which python`, then update your question.

Comment: Okay added which python to my post.  What I am lacking is a bird's eye view of what this all means though, or how to solve the issue.  I might be able to down load the "requests" package separately, but not sure then what directory to manually put it into.

Comment: If you really need so many different python environments I recommend using some version/package manager, so you can easily switch between environments and check which one has which packages. For example: [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), [pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) or [anaconda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html). It will make your life much easier.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/56155402/325452 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell you have three versions of Python on your system.

- The one that comes with OSX `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`
- Python 2.7 from python.org `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
- Python 3.4 from python.org

pip is installed against the Python 2.7 version you downloaded (the one you see in your Applications folder), unfortunately the *default Python* for your shell is the one that's bundled with OSX, and there is no pip installed there.

IDLE is also bundled with the Python that you downloaded, which is why it keeps telling you that pip is installed, but it doesn't work from the shell.

Since you are probably using the Python downloaded from python.org as your "primary" Python (after all, its the one with IDLE that you are using), you need to set your shell environment to point to this Python as default.

The easiest way to do that is to add a variable in `.bashrc` that creates an alias `python` and points it to the right binary. To do that, add this line to `/Users/yourusername/.bashrc` - files with `.` are hidden by default, so you'll have to write the entire file name in the command line to open it.  Add the following line:

```
alias python=/Library/Python/2.7/python
```

Save the file and then close all terminal windows and open it again. Now type `pip` and it should work correctly, and then you can proceed to installing requests.

For future reference, try to stick with one version of Python. I personally ignore the bundled version and use the one from [`brew`](http://brew.sh/), but you can stick to the Python downloaded from python.org.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer!  Typing pip in the terminal did confirm that it now sees it.  I seem to be getting a new error now, which I have added to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Used "sudo" and the package installed!

Comment: I did this and it caused problems

Comment: What problems did it cause?

Comment: Correction: The Python that comes with OS X should be under /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework. The one mentioned above was likely installed with Homebrew or Kyngchaos QGIS.

Answer (score 7):

I met the same question, and error info is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'
```

and finally solved by

```
brew install python3

brew link python3

sudo python3 -m pip install xxx
// or `sudo python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed mine with:

`brew reinstall python`

It fixed all my broken paths. I think I broke it with a broken brew package that had a wrong python version dependancy or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I did some reading. The command line,

```
python3.10 -m pip install pandas
```

as long as you have the latest version of `pip` updated, this will install `pandas` to the specific `python` that you wanted otherwise it defaults to the latest version installed in my case Anaconda. You can change the `python3.10` for your desired version of `python` to install too.

Answer (score 0):

site.py is a standard module that is run by python by default. It allows tweaking sys.path and running some code before your code starts running. It should live in the standard  library and can hardly be somehow absent. However, you can disable automatic importing of the module by passing -S switch to python.

Anyway, you should somehow inspect why the module can not be imported. Try to examine sys.path list.

Comment: Okay I added that to my original post.  I'm not sure what I am looking at though.  Does anything jump out as a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install the package in '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests' but it requires root permissions to do so. This should do the trick:

```
$ sudo pip install requests
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install requests
```