# Installing modules on IDLE

Tags: python, module

I am fairly new to Python and am trying to install matplotlib and numpy onto the IDLE from python.org. I am using a Mac, and everything online tells me to use the command line to install using something like "pip install matplotlib" but the IDLE doesn't have any command line connected to it.

I have already managed to install pip but still am unable to import the modules I need from it. How can I do this?

Comment: you have to run `pip install 'whatever_module'` on your terminal, not on IDLE. once you've done that, you can just type `import 'whatever_module'` in IDLE to use that library. Keep in mind that IDLE is just [python REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) and shouldn't really be used for actually writing full python scripts.

Comment: @RNar I was able to install the modules with the terminal but I could only import them when using the Python built into the terminal. Any time I tried to import on the IDLE it said there was no such module

Comment: This may be caused by you having [multiple versions of Python on your computer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25969007/5323213). Make sure that the python version IDLE is using and your terminal is using is the same. This is easily checked: when you open both of them, the first line should have the version number.

Comment: You might want to use `pip3` instead of just `pip`, depending on how your Python is configured.

Comment: To be honest, I would recommend jumping straight to just using anaconda here, because if you need numpy and matplotlib right now, you're probably going to need many of the other installed packages too.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import call
call(['pip', 'install', 'MODULE'])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although this might be a solution, consider supporting your answer with sufficient reasons and if necessary with useful links as to why this answer solves the OP's problem.

Comment: this does not work