# ImportError: No module named site - mac

Tags: python, terminal

I have had this problem for months. every time that I want to get a new python package and use it I get this error in terminal:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I don't know why do I get this error. actually, I can't use any new package because every time that I wanna install one I get this error. I searched and I found out that the problem would be for PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME but I don't know what they are and how can I change them.
My operating system is mac os and I don't know how to solve this problem in mac.

every time that I open the terminal I  use these two commands to solve the problem:

```
unset PYTHONHOME
unset PYTHONPATH
```

but the next time I get the error again.

Comment: What are you doing exactly when you try to get a new python package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named site on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/importerror-no-module-named-site-on-windows)

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy: Using pip install. for example, I wanted to get nilearn and I used this command: `pip install -U --user nilearn`

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE : It told for windows and I don't know how to do it for mac?

Comment: Have you tried completely reinstalling python? `site-packages` is, by my understanding, one of the fundamental/core libraries and should be built-in to your python installation. If it's not there then something is borked.

Comment: Why installing in `--user` mode? Your user environment may be corrupted… It is not very useful unless you want to install a kind of dev tool (like pipx). Why not using a [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io)?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy yes I tried but I have the problem again. maybe some broken files left on my computer even when I uninstall python. I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

The Python tooling is evolving in Mac OS X such that Python 2.7 is being deprecated. System default paths may no longer apply as I learned after upgrading to Mac OS X Catalina (10.15.x). There are a few scenarios here:

1. **GENERIC FIX** -- According to [this primer on the site package and Python internal paths](https://pymotw.com/2/site/), Python 2.7 requires a specific user path for site packages. The solution I settled on was simply this:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   ```

   At that point you will have a dedicated directory for Python modules (for Python to function). (NOTE that the error `ImportError: No module named site` is misleading as it really indicates that the correct directory structure didn't exist to allow the `site` module to properly load.)
2. **BASIC ALTERNATIVE** -- Is your `PYTHONHOME` pointing to Python3 and your `python --version` reporting **2.7**? Does `python3 --version` report something different (or work at all)? This error started happening for me after the Catalina upgrade when I was trying to use built-ins. Check your `.profile` and `.bash_profile` to see if they are explicitly setting a custom `PYTHONHOME` and/or `PYTHONPATH`. One option is to change that so the `ENV` variables are set explicitly and manually only when a newer Python is needed. You may consider symlinking `python3` and `pip3` to leave the standard commands to the OS.
3. **DEBUGGING** -- If you would like to test and/or get more information, try executing Python in one of the increasingly verbose modes:

   ```
   python -v
   python -vv
   python -vvv
   ```